# Print out 10 random numbers between 2 numbers in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I need some help in my programming course for python, I'm currently coding in python3.

I have menu based program where you can do various of things, I'm currently trying to create a option where the program will print out 10 numbers between 2 numbers that the user have already enterd using simple:

- num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
- num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))

I need help witht the function that takes care of the randomizing part of the 10 numbers that will be printed out between 2 numbers that are already enterd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**
Here is a list of 10 elements in between `num1` and `num2`

```
[random.randrange(*sorted([num1,num2])) for i in range(10)]
```

**Why i used `sorted`**

`random.randrange` only take increasing order of number

Here is the execution of code in IPython.

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
Enter your first number: 10
In [3]: num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
Enter your second number: 100
In [4]: for rand_num in [random.randrange(*sorted([num1,num2])) for i in range(10)]:
   .....:     print rand_num
   .....:     
69
63
14
22
98
39
66
21
26
72
```

**Method 2**

Here we use `random.sample`. If the `range(num1,num2)` have more than 10 population then only this method is valid.

```
random.sample(range(*sorted([num1,num2])),10)
```

Example of execution.

```
In [1]: random.sample(range(1,100),10)
Out[1]: [55, 5, 91, 19, 11, 42, 37, 45, 79, 86]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
num1, num2 = 10, 100
for i in range(0,10):
    print random.randrange(num1, num2)
```